# Optimize/faster choice than "not all" in LINQ

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, linq

I'm using EF 6 and .NET Framework 4.6.1. I have a scenario where I need to exclude a parent record if all of its child records meet a certain condition.

This is a generic version of what I've done so far:

```cs
public ParentRecords GetParentRecordsExceptWhereSpecificStringOnAllChildren(string aSpecificString){ 
        return ParentRecords
            .Where(parent => !parent.ChildRecords
                .Select(child => child.SomeStringProperty)
                .All(c => c.Equals(aSpecificString))
        );
    }
```

This takes a little too much time to run (on the scale of one second per child record), and the generated SQL from EF contains n-1 `UNION ALL` statements, where n is the number of child records.

I suspect I'm missing an obvious way to write this that would improve performance dramatically, but I'm not seeing it (but I'm not a LINQ/EF master by any means).

I wrote a stored procedure that returns the same data, but much faster, and not exactly in the same layout (one flat row versus a row for each child record). We're trying to avoid stored procedures, though, so I'm back to the grindstone on figuring out how to make this LINQ faster.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. If I haven't explained this clearly, please let me know. I tried to make it generic for the sake of re-use, in case anyone else is in this situation.

Comment: I would suggest to try excluding a record if at least one child record doesn't meet a criteria: `.Any(c => !c.Equals(aSpecificString))`

Comment: Holy crap, that's perfect. Thank you! I'll try that!

Comment: It probably makes little difference, but you don't really need the `Select` either. You should be able to do `.Any(c => !c.SomeStringProperty.Equals(aSpecificString))`

Comment: Oo. I'll try that, too. So far this looks to be much faster (100 ms or so, versus 5400 ms).

Comment: @RomanKoliada that's much faster, thank you. I'm not entirely sure why, as the generated SQL still shows a ton of `UNION ALL` statements, but it's definitely much faster. If you create an 'answer' from your comment, I'll mark it the answer.

Comment: I think i'm seeing the `UNION ALL`  because I'm projecting (`.Select(item => new ModelForThisData ... `) and some of the projection properties are lists. That's on me; I can fix that.

Comment: @MattBurland I think that does help. Removing the `Select` I think simplified the generated SQL a bit. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the select of SomeStringProperty from your code.

Using Any

```
        ParentRecords.Where(parent =>
            parent.ChildRecords.Any(child => !child.SomeStringProperty.Equals(aSpecificString)));
```

Using All

```
       ParentRecords.Where(parent =>
            !parent.ChildRecords.All(child => child.SomeStringProperty.Equals(aSpecificString)));
```

Comment: These changes (removing the `Select` and using `Any` ultimately fixed the performance issue I was seeing, so I'm marking this as the answer.